# yum: how to see processes affected by an upgrade?

Tags: linux, yum

While **zypper** offers a "ps" option to show processes currently using deleted/upgraded files, **yum** appears to lack such an option...

How do you know with **yum** if there are processes needing to be restarted?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to install yum plugin `yum-plugin-ps`:

```
Installed Packages
Name        : yum-plugin-ps
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 1.1.31
Release     : 2.fc16
Size        : 29 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : fedora
Summary     : Yum plugin to look at processes, with respect to packages
URL         : http://yum.baseurl.org/download/yum-utils/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : When this plugin is installed it adds the yum command "ps", which allows you
            : to see which running processes are accociated with which packages (and if they
            : need rebooting, or have updates, etc.)
```

Comment: Great!
That did the trick - question answered!